# free online sql database hosting for java desktop project

Tags: sql, hosting

i have a local database in wampserver and I want to host it online. is there any option to any free hosting sites online? I tried freesqldatabase.com but am told it can only hold records up to 100 MB in size for a package of 5 databases. please any suggestions are welcomed. I want to connect to a java desktop project. thank you

Comment: Look into AWS (Amazon Web Services).  They have a service called RDS which can host a large variety of common RDBMS.  Also, they have a free tier, which probably can meet your immediate needs.

Comment: ok bro, will try it out. thanks